# Linking two verbs --> 送り始める

Tags: verbs

I just stumbled across the following sentence:

来週から家庭に布のマスクを**送り始める**

And was wondering what kind of construct this 送り始める is.  送り is no verb-ending known to me but looks like the stem of the -masu form (infinite?). Is this a common pattern to link two verbs? Is there any grammatical name for this concept so I can find more information about it?

So far I only learnt that the te form can be used to combine two verbs: 送って始める, but I guess in that case they are shifted in time?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Verb Masu + 始める` is an example of a compound verb in which the dominant meaning comes from Verb 1 and a qualification comes from Verb 1. In the case of 送り始める, the dominant meaning is taken from Verb 1 (送る to send) and the qualification comes from Verb 2 (始める to start, to begin). The overall meaning becomes "to start sending" or "to start to send". Other examples:

> 話し始める to begin to speak
>   食べ始める to start eating
>   降り始める to start falling

There are many other compound verbs in Japanese. A quick search on this site will show up plenty of other instances.